# CSS banner slider with links and target

Tags: css, wordpress, image, slider

I'm currently testing an image banner slider. It looks fine. But when it cames for clicking on each image all they go to the same link (the last one). Also I'm trying to make each link open in _blank target but it doesn't work to. Here's the code:

```css
.slider {
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider>div {
  position: absolute;
  animation: move_slide2 30s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

@keyframes move_slide {
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes move_slide2 {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.nossaseguros.ao/pt/nossa-seguros/noticias/campanha-de-divulgacao-do-produto-automovel" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=1" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://bancobai.ao/en/companies/products-and-services/e-kwanza-bai-1" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.caixaangola.ao/inicio/particulares/solucoes.poupancas/dp-antecipa/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=3" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.caixaangola.ao/inicio/particulares/solucoes.poupancas/dp-antecipa/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=4" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.caixaangola.ao/inicio/particulares/solucoes.poupancas/dp-antecipa/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=5" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because you're only animating the **opacity**, all the elements are still there in their original order. So when we click on the banner we're always going to be clicking on the same item, in this case the last item, but it will be *invisible*.

Comment: You'll want to use [javascript to show/hide elements](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) when that element is out of view/not supposed to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pointer events to none by default and then when opacity is at 1, change the pointer events back to auto and this should make the shown link clickable:

```css
.slider {
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider>div {
  position: absolute;
  animation: move_slide2 30s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

@keyframes move_slide2 {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.nossaseguros.ao/pt/nossa-seguros/noticias/campanha-de-divulgacao-do-produto-automovel" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=1" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://bancobai.ao/en/companies/products-and-services/e-kwanza-bai-1" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.caixaangola.ao/inicio/particulares/solucoes.poupancas/dp-antecipa/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=3" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.caixaangola.ao/inicio/particulares/solucoes.poupancas/dp-antecipa/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=4" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.caixaangola.ao/inicio/particulares/solucoes.poupancas/dp-antecipa/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/728x90?text=5" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for unchecking Your answer. Your solution didn't solve the target issue. The links are supposed to open at _blank but they still open in the same window

Comment: Wordpress deletes  target="_blank" when I save the HTML part

Comment: Then that is a separate question - how to stop wordpress removing target = blank - I have answered this question about how to make your links clickable